# servlet 3.0 @WebServlet use..what will be in web.xml?

Tags: servlets, servlet-3.0

I want to know the directory structure for using servlet 3.0 with Tomcat 7.
I have used annotation @WebServlet without initialization parameters.

I want to know what is to be written in web.xml file then?? 
Is  and  is still to be written...??

The file is stored in the classes folder of the tomcat.

Comment: You dont need any web.xml at all. Please look [here][1]. Explained.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967062/servlet-3-0-import-package-of-annotation

Answer (score 24):

This is all you need in `web.xml`:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">
```

3.0-compatible servlet container (like Tomcat 7) will find `@WebServlet` automatically.

Comment: Is any attribute compulsory for this annotations @WebServlet??

Comment: import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; What is here servlet, annotation and WebServlet a class or interface in the javax package?

Comment: @user460920: none of them are required (otherwise the code would not even compile)

Comment: If I have a gradle project that isn't generating the web.xml properly.. how do I add that ?  Not seeing it in any of the projects in STS..

Answer (score 3):

I read the answer from Tomasz Nurkiewicz which was upvoted by 22 people till now. Please note, he answered **4 years ago**.

I wondered why I needed an almost empty xml file?

And I tried with a hello world with Servlet 3.

```
package com.servlet3;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/helloServlet3")
public class HelloServlet3 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.print("<html><body>");
        out.print("<h3>Hello Servlet</h3>");
        out.print("</body></html>");
    }
}
```

And I am able to run this tiny web-application successfully.

[image]

**Important Note:**

please note, there is **no web.xml exists** in this sample.

[image]

So, we **don't** need **this kind of almost-empty** web.xml.

<s>but, web.xml is **mandatory**, if you need form-based authentication (but, **without Spring** security).because, there is **no equivalent annotation** available for `<login-config`>.</s>

According to this post in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17109266/form-login-in-a-servlet-3-0-using-annotations)

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
  <form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/login?event=Retry</form-error-page>
  </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

... **the only way to configure form-based authentication is by using deployment descriptor (web.xml or web-fragment.xml).**

According to JSR-315 Servlet 3.0 Specification :: Ch13.6.3 (pg132):

> "The web application deployment descriptor contains entries for a
>   login form and error page..."

Specification **only** refers to the web deployment descriptor for form-login configuration, and **not to any annotation**-based configuration.

**UPDATE:**

The above **strike** out information is related to Java **EE6**.

In Java **EE7**, We can do form-based authentication **programmatic way**..

From the Java EE7 [official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-webtier003.htm#GIRCJ),

> **48.3.1 Authenticating Users Programmatically**
>
> The following methods of the HttpServletRequest interface enable you
>   to authenticate users for a web application programmatically.
>
> **authenticate** allows an application to instigate authentication of the
>   request caller by the container from within an unconstrained request
>   context. A login dialog box displays and collects the user name and
>   password for authentication purposes.
>
> **login** allows an application to collect user name and password
>   information as an **alternative** to specifying form-based authentication
>   in an application **deployment descriptor**.
>
> **logout** allows an application to reset the caller identity of a
>   request.

Comment: Question is ...what will be in web.xml? I answered like "nothing" will be in it.Is there anything wrong to comment the other answer? I am puzzled.