# servlet 3.0 import package of annotation

Tags: servlets, servlet-3.0

In Servlets 3.0 we have to import the annotations package. So i want to know what are classes and interfaces?

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
```

What is here servlet, annotation and WebServlet a class or interface in the javax package?

Comment: Actually, you con't have to import it if you don't use those annotations.  (And in fact, you don't *have to* even if you do.  You can use the annotations' fully qualified names ...)  If you want a list of the classes in the package, look at the javadocs: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/package-summary.html

Answer (score 8):

**Before annotations the only way to define any deployment properties was using deployments descriptors. For Web Applications, it was web.xml.**

`From JavaEE 5 annotations were supported` which lets you define certain deployment properties. They were mostly related to resources the servlets used. But still the servlets has to defined in web.xml only.

`Starting with Java EE 6, annotations such as @WebServlet, @WebFilter, @WebListener were introduced` which lets you define the deployment properties in the java class itself. You do not have to mention them in web.xml. `All the properties you can mention in web.xml can now be provided using @WebSerlvet annotation`. And one can still override the properties using web.xml  tag.

**This is how Servlets can be defined using annotation:**

```
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet; 

 @WebServlet(asyncSupported = false, name = "HelloWorldServlet",
  urlPatterns = {"/hello"}, 
  initParams = {@WebInitParam(name="param1", value="value1"),
                @WebInitParam(name="param2", value="value2")}
 )
 public HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet
 {


  public void doGet(HttpSerlvetRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  {
   //write hello world.
  }

 }
```

Comment: perfect! no need for a web.xml!