# Servlet Launch Error - "The requested resource is not available"

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, servlets, browser

I am well aware there have been many, many related questions asked already about this, as well as even more answers. Unfortunately, having tried all this advice I still cannot resolve this problem.

I am trying to launch a simple Java servlet in the browser, following instructions from the textbook:

**Java Programming: Comprehensive Concepts and Techniques, Shelly Cashman Series, ISBN: 9781418859855.**

I am aware of the advice given here to other people with this/similar problems, that servlets should preferably be written under a package, and not packageless, but I am following the textbook's guidance with this, and of course being a textbook, its method must work. I seek help with doing it in THIS method.

I have a Java servlet, called HTMLBank.java which I successfully compiled with no compilation errors. Now, according to the textbook:

1) Place the .class file into **C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes** folder. Yes, the textbook uses the default package for this and the ROOT directory of Tomcat.

2) Run the Tomcat service - it is running (shown as a green "play" arrow in right-bottom of the screen).

3) In the browser, type URL: **http://localhost:8080/servlet/HTMLBank** and enter it. After doing this, the following error results:

[The Error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97SXe.png)

Now, I might mention that I did succeed in launching a servlet once before, but that was only if I used a package, say com.example and mapped it in the web.xml file, but as stated before, this deviates from the textbook and I need to get it to work using the default package and ROOT directory.

Here is the code of the HTMLBank.java servlet file:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class HTMLBank extends HttpServlet
{
    public void init() throws ServletException {}

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        response.setHeader("Expires", "Tues, 01 Jan 1980 00:00:00 GMT");

        out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<title>Online Bank ATM Simulator</title>");
            out.println("<h1>Tester Text.</h1>");
            out.println("<body>This serves to test functioning of the servlet in browser.</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }

    public void destroy(){}
}
```

Here is the code of the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

  <display-name>Welcome to Tomcat</display-name>
  <description>
     Welcome to Tomcat
  </description>

<!-- JSPC servlet mappings start -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>org.apache.jsp.index_jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

<!-- JSPC servlet mappings end -->

<-- added the following for invoker servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>invoker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.apache.catalina.servlets.InvokerServlet
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>invoker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/servlet/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

The web.xml file was modified per book guide to allow locating anonymous servlets in the default directory.

Here is the context.xml file:

```
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context reloadable="true">     <!-- Enabled Tomcat Servlet reloading -->

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <WatchedResource>META-INF/context.xml</WatchedResource>

    <!-- Uncomment this to disable session persistence across Tomcat restarts -->
    <!--
    <Manager pathname="" />
    -->

</Context>
```

This file was edited to enable servlet reloading, also as per book guide.

The following are paths to all the files/folders involved in this discussion:

**C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes**      -->     I created the "classes" folder, per book guide.

**C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\HTMLBank.class**      -->    I placed the .class file into here.

**C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\web.xml**     -->    This is the location of web.xml file which was edited.

**C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\conf\context.xml** is the location of the context.xml file which was edited.

So, as I said, I need to work the servlet without a package and from ROOT. How do I do that ?

I also post the content of an error log file generated by Tomcat, if it helps to identify the issue:

```
08 Sep 2017 10:47:53 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
08 Sep 2017 10:47:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 3887 ms
08 Sep 2017 10:47:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
08 Sep 2017 10:47:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/5.5.7
08 Sep 2017 10:47:54 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost start
INFO: XML validation disabled
08 Sep 2017 10:47:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: org.apache.webapp.balancer.BalancerFilter: init(): ruleChain: [org.apache.webapp.balancer.RuleChain: [org.apache.webapp.balancer.rules.URLStringMatchRule: Target string: News / Redirect URL: http://www.cnn.com], [org.apache.webapp.balancer.rules.RequestParameterRule: Target param name: paramName / Target param value: paramValue / Redirect URL: http://www.yahoo.com], [org.apache.webapp.balancer.rules.AcceptEverythingRule: Redirect URL: http://jakarta.apache.org]]
08 Sep 2017 10:47:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
08 Sep 2017 10:47:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
08 Sep 2017 10:47:57 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester fatalError
SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 42 column 2: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.startOfMarkup(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4020)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1019)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1011)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:450)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:537)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:409)
08 Sep 2017 10:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Parse error in application web.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1561)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationWebConfig(ContextConfig.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.start(ContextConfig.java:959)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4020)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:759)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:524)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:872)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:310)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1019)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:718)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1011)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:450)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:537)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:409)
08 Sep 2017 10:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig applicationWebConfig
SEVERE: Occurred at line 42 column 2
08 Sep 2017 10:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig start
SEVERE: Marking this application unavailable due to previous error(s)
08 Sep 2017 10:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error getConfigured
08 Sep 2017 10:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context startup failed due to previous errors
08 Sep 2017 10:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextInitialized()
08 Sep 2017 10:47:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextInitialized()
08 Sep 2017 10:47:58 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
08 Sep 2017 10:47:58 AM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK2: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
08 Sep 2017 10:47:58 AM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/152  config=null
08 Sep 2017 10:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.storeconfig.StoreLoader load
INFO: Find registry server-registry.xml at classpath resource
08 Sep 2017 10:47:58 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4765 ms
09 Sep 2017 10:44:16 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol pause
INFO: Pausing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('org.apache.catalina.jsp_classpath', '/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/webapps/servlets-examples/WEB-INF/classes/;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/shared/classes/;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/classes/;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/i18n/tomcat-i18n-en.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/i18n/tomcat-i18n-es.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/i18n/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/i18n/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/commons-el.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/jasper-compiler-jdt.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/jasper-compiler.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/jasper-runtime.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/jsp-api.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/naming-factory-dbcp.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/naming-factory.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/naming-resources.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/servlet-api.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%205.5/bin/bootstrap.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/dnsns.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/localedata.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES', '[Ljava.lang.String;@257f1b')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('javax.servlet.context.tempdir', 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\work\Catalina\localhost\servlets-examples')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('org.apache.catalina.resources', 'org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext@1bbdd48')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES', '[Ljava.lang.String;@1d6fbb3')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeReplaced('org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES', '[Ljava.lang.String;@1d6fbb3')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeReplaced('org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES', '[Ljava.lang.String;@126d3df')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('org.apache.catalina.jsp_classpath', '/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/webapps/jsp-examples/WEB-INF/classes/;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/webapps/jsp-examples/WEB-INF/lib/jstl.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/webapps/jsp-examples/WEB-INF/lib/standard.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/shared/classes/;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/classes/;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/i18n/tomcat-i18n-en.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/i18n/tomcat-i18n-es.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/i18n/tomcat-i18n-fr.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/i18n/tomcat-i18n-ja.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/commons-el.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/jasper-compiler-jdt.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/jasper-compiler.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/jasper-runtime.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/jsp-api.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/naming-factory-dbcp.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/naming-factory.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/naming-resources.jar;/C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 5.5/common/lib/servlet-api.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Apache%20Software%20Foundation/Tomcat%205.5/bin/bootstrap.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/dnsns.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/localedata.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/servlet-api.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/sunmscapi.jar;/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre6/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES', '[Ljava.lang.String;@c5aa00')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('javax.servlet.context.tempdir', 'C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\work\Catalina\localhost\jsp-examples')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeRemoved('org.apache.catalina.resources', 'org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext@11c0d60')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeAdded('org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES', '[Ljava.lang.String;@136d9d8')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeReplaced('org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES', '[Ljava.lang.String;@136d9d8')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: attributeReplaced('org.apache.catalina.WELCOME_FILES', '[Ljava.lang.String;@1827d1')
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
09 Sep 2017 10:44:18 AM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
```

Comment: Have you tried  http://localhost:8080/<your_app_name>/servlet/HTMLBank ( replace <your_app_name> with the actual name)

Comment: Hey, dsp_user. Thank you, just tried it - the issue persists. What do you mean by the <your_app_name>? Is it the servlet's .class file name? In that case it is HTMLBank.class (from HTMLBank.java).

Comment: <your_app_name> is actually the name of your project as it appears in the IDE (your servlet class name may or may not match this name).

Comment: Project name - I have no such separate name anywhere in this project. There isn't even a custom folder having the same or related name to the .class file name. I have the .class file under the directory:

C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 5.5\webapps\ROOT\WEB-INF\classes\HTMLBank.class

So the only name involved here is "HTMLBank". What should I insert in that URL space you indicate?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so, go to your workspace folder and then find your project (it should be there). You will find a .project file, which contains the project name (you whole project is under this name in the IDE)

Comment: No, I'm using TextPad v.4.7.3 by Helios Software Solutions.

I write as well as compile the Java servlets in this program. As far as I checked in TextPad, there is no such thing as "project name" or anything similar.

Comment: I suggest switching to a proper IDE (e.g. Eclipse or Netbeans), which does take some time to get used to but you'll be much more productive. Also, Tomcat 5.5 is a bit dated now so try using a more recent Tomcat installation and follow some web application tutorials. Not much point in  trying an example from the now ancient book. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the example is a "prequel" to a few bigger servlets that I need to write and run successfully - they are for my last assignment, which is to be submitted for evaluation. They will check how I do everything using the methods given in this book, I doubt they'll agree to anything else.

Is there really nothing that you can see as errors - syntax, logic or referencing, or other - in my post?

I assume that because the servlet compiles without errors, that means as to coding there are no errors. It must then be something to do with referencing (URL - web.xml)...

Comment: I've worked with servlets in the past (but with more recent Tomcat versions) and correct URLs always included a project name (this project name is not specified in the mapping though so no need to change your web.xml).  Since you're not using an IDE, I'm not even sure that you have a .project file but I'm pretty sure that a project for your application still exists.

Comment: I've checked in TextPad, and the Web for project names in TextPad, but even Web has nothing on TextPad and .project files or the like.

Could there really be such a fatal mistake in the textbook? If it was critical to have an extra section in the URL that specifies a project folder then the textbook would state it.

I also read somewhere that there is a way to run a servlet without any use of a web.xml file, I think they say you need to use the full path to the servlet as the URL, but there wasn't really information on this on the Web. Would you know if this is true and how to do this?

Comment: Another thing - another Java expert told me that from JDK 1.4 and up, it is impossible to use the default servlet way of launching servlet and so every servlet MUST have a custom package defined.

I indeed have JDK 1.5.xx but if this really is the issue I'm shocked the textbook, in which came the CD with this version JDK and Tomcat, makes no slightest mention of this consideration.

Comment: Web.xml is optional for servlet 3.0 and later (annotations are used instead) but unfortunately Tomcat 5.5 doesn't support 3.0 so you're pretty much stuck ( you can find more information here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478862/why-web-xml-is-removed-from-servlet-3-0 ). Also, I'm not saying that the docs is wrong, I'm just saying what I had to do (add a project name to the URL) but I'm using more recent version of Tomcat (and servlet)

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post to include the content of the error log file generated by Tomcat, for you to look at. I'm a novice at Java, so I can't understand much of this file, but I'm sure you and other experts here will.

Please let me know if the issue is actually addressed by this error log file.

Comment: The error says that web.xml is malformed though I don't see it. Try removing the * in the servlet mapping (leave just /servlet/ )

Comment: I just tried it, but the issue persists.

What about the consideration of JDK version VS which version and up doesn't support default servlets?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, guys, I solved this problem:

The error log actually shows that line 42 of the web.xml file has an error. I examined that line and found a very stupid typo right at the beginning - the comment beginning tag was incorrect. Almost 3 weeks of searching in wrong places because I never would have thought to check something like this.

Thanks nonetheless to everybody who replied, it was much appreciated!